# CSS- Word is not wrapping in this case- word-wrap not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to wrap word in div. My css is

```
.event-location {
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
height: 90px;
line-height: 90px;
white-space: nowrap;
word-wrap: break-word;
width: 100%;
word-break: break-all;
background-color: #337AB7;
font-size: 18px;
padding-left: 10px;
font-weight: bold;
border-radius: 3px;}
```

In this case long line without sapces going outside the div.

Comment: you must choose between `word-wrap: break-word;` and `word-break: break-all;`; each one breaks the words in a different point.

Answer (score 4):

You are using `white-space:nowrap;` which causes you not to break the text apart. So, you may remove that or set to normal:

```
white-space:normal;
```